# Aggregate no R utilizando data como chave

Tags: r

Boa tarde,

Estou utilizando o código:

```
soma<-aggregate(as.numeric(coop[c(10,18,26,34,42,50,58,66)]), by=list(coop$data), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

para agregar os dados com base na chave data, que está em formato de data. Tentei mudar essa variável para numérico ou string, mas volta o mesmo erro:

```
Error in aggregate(as.numeric(coop[c(10, 18, 26, 34, 42, 50, 58, 66)]),:
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

O deveria estar fazendo?
Já fiz vários outros aggregates e não havia me deparado com esse erro. Existem valores em NA na base, mas não acredito que esse seja o problema.

Comment: Tente fazer o seu código reproduzível!

Comment: `coop`não me parece ser um vetor, e sim um data.frame. Sendo assim, me parece que você precisa selecionar qual coluna você está agregando. Do jeito que está fazendo: `coop[c(...)]` você está selecionando diversas linhas de um data.frame (que é igual a uma lista) e não pode ser convertido para um valor numérico.

Comment: O problema está sendo na hora de converter o coop[c(...)] em numérico.

Comment: sim, pq isso não pode ser convertido em numérico: é um data.frame. o que dá `class(coop[c(...)])`

Comment: Você tem razão. Bobeira minha. Aproveitei e transformei tudo em numérico: dados[,10:67]<-sapply(dados[,10:67], as.numeric)